# Why does JS throw a Type Error when I try to connect audio to a Biquad Filter?

Tags: javascript, audio, typeerror, web-audio-api

I’ve been dabbling in the WebAudio API, and for some reason I cannot get the Biquad Filter to work. My oscillators, envelopes, and custom effects all work fine, but the filter has been giving me trouble.

I have a master gain control `vca` which I want to send through my filter out to `context.destination`. `vca` is defined simply as such:

```
var vca = context.createGain();
vca.gain.value = 0.3
```

I’ve built my filter like this:

```
function lowpass() {
  var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
  filter.type = 'lowpass';
  filter.frequency.value = 1000
}
var filt = new lowpass
```

When I attempt to run the following, CodePen throws a Type Error:

```
vca.connect(filt);
filt.connect(context.destination)
```

Why is this happening? Is it something wrong with the filter settings, my method of connecting the VCA? The way I’ve constructed the filter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way you create a new filter. `lowpass()` is a regular function but the `new` keyword treats it like a constructor.

You can fix your code by calling it as a regular function and returning the `filter` from it.

```
function lowpass() {
  var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
  filter.type = 'lowpass';
  filter.frequency.value = 1000
  return filter;
}
var filt = lowpass()
```

If want to go one step further you can pass the `context` into the function instead of relying on `context` to be defined in the outer scope to make it a bit cleaner.

```
function lowpass(context) {
  var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
  filter.type = 'lowpass';
  filter.frequency.value = 1000
  return filter;
}
var filt = lowpass(context)
```

Comment: That fixed it––your answer also illuminated other problems in my code with calling `new` on non-constructor functions. I also changed my method for frequency to `filter.frequency.setValueAtTime(1000, context.currentTime)`, which might have made a difference.